# QGIS PDF export with different colours

Tags: pdf

So im trying to export a large map (44"x60") and when i export to pdf, some of my vector colours get changed. Specifically, i have a few vector layers with polygons using "dense 5" fill style and these are the ones that are affected. they come out darker than they should be.

Ive used this fill style on other projects befor and it has exported fine.
I can export these as tiff and they colours turn out fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone else have this issue with exporting pdfs?